# How can I get rid of urls that contain special characters like, "#", and text chunks like, ".pdf" from a string array of urls?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, jsoup

How can I get rid of urls that contain special characters like, "#", and small string like, ".pdf" from a string array of urls?

I am making a web spider. The goal is to be able to generate an entire list of urls of a website, minus the stuff I don't want. The spider goes to the home page, grabs the urls, then visits each url, then visits each url on those urls that it hasn't previously visited.

I am attempting to purify the data it gives me by getting rid of urls that have, ".zip", ".pdf", a "+", or a "#" in them from my string array.

I attempted to do it with a version of the following if statement, this is a simplified version of it that assumes there is a string array full of urls and an int called TotalNumberOfUrls with the total number of urls.

```
String j = "";

while( x != TotalNumberOfUrls)
{

j = ValueOfGiantStringArray[x];
    if(!(j.contains("#")) || !(j.contains("+")) || !(j.contains(".pdf")) || !(j.contains(".zip")))
    {
//Runs a scraping module on the url contained in the string j.
    }

x++;
}
```

This didn't work for me. For some reason, my scraper is running within this if statements even when j has a value of, "https://procomps.com/cherry-services/cadalog/#content" for example.
It doesn't detect the # for some reason.

What is the best way to weed out urls with these unwanted characters and text chunks from my string array of urls?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `||`s to `&&`s in the condition of your `if` statement. This way, the code inside the `if` block will only run if none of the characters you don't want are in the url.

Comment: I just attempted this. Here is one of the urls that passed through: https://procomps.com/tag/unilifter-systems/#  I used this if(!(j.contains("#")) && !(j.contains("+")) && !(j.contains(".pdf")) && !(j.contains(".zip")))
             {

Comment: I copied and pasted your if statement and tested with the example input you gave. The code inside the `if` block wasn't running for me as intended. Check out this link to test it yourself. https://www.onlinegdb.com/JaHf4UjFb

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is wrong. Generally if you want to express `Something doesn't contain a or b or c` is something like  `!( contains(a) || contains(b) || contains(c) )` or according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) the following equivalent expression `!contains(a) && !contains(b) && !contains(c)`

Assuming you have an array which somehow looks similar to the following and you are using a while loop something like below should work:

```
String[] myURLs = { "someURL.com/somePath/file.zip",
                    "someURL.com/somePath/blabla#blup",
                    "someURL.com/somePath/another.pdf",
                    "someURL.com/somePath/some-content",
                    "http://myapp/mypage/mycontent",
                    "http://myapp/my+test/jjj"};
String j = "";

int x = 0;
while( x != myURLs.length) {
    j = myURLs[x];
    if( !(j.contains("#") || j.contains("+") || j.contains(".pdf") || j.contains(".zip")) ) {
        //Runs a scraping module on the url contained in the string j.
        System.out.println("Scraping content from URL: " + j);
    }
    x++;
}
```

IMO a for loop would make your code more readable than a while loop. Using the same array as above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myURLs.length; i++) {
    String temp = myURLs[i];
    if( !(temp.contains("#") || temp.contains("+") || temp.contains(".pdf") || temp.contains(".zip")) ) {
        //Runs a scraping module on the url contained in the string temp.
        System.out.println("Scraping content from URL: " + temp);
    }
}
```

If you want to play around with Java-8 features

```
Set<String> exclude = Set.of("#", "+", ".pdf", ".zip");
Arrays.stream(myURLs)
        .filter(url -> !exclude.stream().anyMatch(url::contains))
        .forEach(url -> {
            //Runs a scraping module on the url contained in the string url.
            System.out.println("Scraping content from URL: " + url);
        });
```

or regular expressions

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#|\\+|\\.pdf|\\.zip");
for (String url : myURLs) {
    if(!pattern.matcher(url).find()){
        //Runs a scraping module on the url contained in the string url.
        System.out.println("Scraping content from URL: " + url);
    }
}
```